# Ĉu "preta" estas speciala adjektivo pro la rilato kun infinitivo?

Tags: grammar

Mi hodiaŭ aŭdis interparoladon en la esperanta kaj unu frazo vekis mian atenton:

```
Sed ĝi estas tute maljuna hundo, preta morti!
```

Por mi estis strange aŭdi tiun `preta morti` en la rolo de adjektivo. La frazo kompreneblis, sed la konstruo adjektivo+infinitivo aspektis strange.

Mi kontrolis Tekstaron kaj mi trovis ekzemple tiun ĉi frazon (La batalo de l’ vivo, Zamenhof):

```
du el miaj plej bonaj jaroj mi staris
post la pordo de butiko de
librovendisto, preta postkuri, ...
```

Tie, *preta postkuri* estas pli adverba tamen (komparu kun *"stari garde" (Z)*) sed ĝi havas la saman formon.

Ĉu vi povas pensi pri aliaj adjektivoj, kiuj akceptus infinitivon por krei tiajn adjektivajn/adverbajn unuojn?

```
 preta morti
```

Aŭ ĉu `preta` estas aparta?

Answer (score 2):

[PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/index.html) havas kelkajn ekzemplojn kun "preta + i-verbo".

> Ŝi estis tute preta eldiri sian konfeson de amo.
>
> Mi ĉiam estas preta fervori en servado al la patrujo.
>
> Tio tiel kortuŝis la soldaton, ke li estis preta plori.
>
> Ili estas pretaj fari atencon kontraŭ mia vivo.

La lasta ekzemplo havas [aldonon](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/rekta_priskribo.html), ke oni ankaŭ povas uzi por + i-verbo: kapabla por instrui, preta por fari.

Mi komprenas la esprimon tiel, ke la adjektivo (preta, kapabla eble aliaj) normale priskribas la subjekton kaj la i-verbo rolas kiel komplemento al tiu adjektivo. Ŝi estis preta → preta eldiri. Eble la originala frazo sonas strange al vi pro rekta uzo de la i-verbo anstataŭ por + i-verbo. Pravas, ke "por" ĝenerale esprimas la celon, sed oni devas memori, ke la i-verbo havas pli ampleksan uzon ol la infinitivo en tiaj lingvoj, kiu havas nur unu infinitivon. (Kaj tial PMEG evitas uzi tradiciajn gramatikajn terminojn.)

Comment: Dankon pro la klarigo kaj citaĵoj. Kvankam mi komprenas kaj la frazon kaj la uzon, mi ŝatus scii ĉu aliaj adjektivoj, krom preta, akceptas tiun seperan aldonon de -i formo por krei unuon adjektivan. Vi trovis `kapabla` (kiu cetere estas multe pli produktema), sed mi ankoraŭ sentas ke temas pri specialaj adjektivoj. Ĉu eble pro tio ke ili iel ne tutas sen tiu akompana -i formo? (ĉu subkomprenita ĉu menciita, kaj por `preta` nur por [la dua signifo](http://vortaro.net/#preta)).

Comment: Mi samopinias, ke devas temi pri specialaj adjektivoj. Mi rezonas tiel, ke la adjektivo devas esti tia, ke ĝi priskribas iun **staton** de la ago de la verbo. Minimume "preta" kaj "kapabla" estas tiaj. Kontraŭe ekz. "Mi estas bela fari tion" estas sensenca, ĉar "bela" neniel povas priskribi staton de "fari". Kp. "bele fari" kie "bele" priskribas manieron, ne staton.